# How to insert and read time/date in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I want to read the single day, month and year, without adding 3 extra MySQL-rows, in this format (with PHP):

```
day: 01
month: Jan, Feb, Mar..(first three letters)
year: 2011
```

This is table and PHP script, which I use now:

I add the date with PHP:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (...,`time`) VALUES (...'".date(d.".".m.".".Y)."');");
```

I read it out with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news";
$result = mysql_query ($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
echo $row['time'];
}
```

MySQL table:

```
news:
time(text):
"27.03.2011"
```

Comment: I'm confused, why are you not just using one of MySQL's built in date/time types, like date? An internal MySQL date would be Y-m-d, not d.m.Y. Furthermore, you're using `date()` incorrectly - the date codes are in a string, so for this (which I'm not recommending, just correcting your code) it would be `date('d.m.Y')`. But there's no reason to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (...,`time`) VALUES (...'".date(d.".".M.".".Y)."');");
```

M instead of m gives you the 3 letter textual representation of the month.

Get it with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
    echo date( 'd', strtotime( str$row['time'] ) );
    echo date( 'M', strtotime( str$row['time'] ) );
    echo date( 'Y', strtotime( str$row['time'] ) );
}
```

Read more on:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thnaks. that was the time-config i was searching for ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can either do it in PHP, check the [strftime function](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strftime.php) or use in SELECT something like

```
   SELECT DAY(date) as day, MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year FROM table
```

and in php you would acccess it as $result['day']. $result['month'] etc. the "date" in SELECT query is of course the name of the column in which you store your date. I would recommend strftime

Answer (score 1):

You can use MONTH(), DAY(), YEAR() Mysql functions., i.e,

```
SELECT MONTH(`time`) AS `month`, DAY(`time`) AS `day`, YEAR(`time`) AS `year` FROM `news` [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, substring(1,2) as day, substring(4,2) as month, substring(7) as year FROM table
```

Also you can(and should) use `date` table format and use `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()` functions

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `DATETIME` column in your mysql table.  MySQL is then responsible for storing the date in its own internal format, and you can retrieve it in any format you need.

To insert the current date, you can simply

```
INSERT INTO news (...,`time`) VALUES (...,NOW())
```

To retrieve it in the format you want, use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`time`, '%d.%b.%Y');
```

[Documentation on MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)